# Rails & MongoID aggregate function for user's dialog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I have collection of messages which contains receiver_user_id and sender_user_id.

```
  class Message
    field :content, type: String
    field :created_at, type: DateTime, :default => DateTime.now

    belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'sender_user_id', inverse_of: 'outcomnig_messages'
    belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'receiver_user_id', inverse_of: 'incoming_messages'
  end
```

I have id of user, what is current user, and need to get list of dialogs. I need to get list of dialogs something like this

```
{
    _id: '%collocutor_id%',
    count: %messages count%,
    messages: [{%array of messages with this user ordered by created_at desc%}]
}
```

Comment: `@user.incoming_messages.order(created_at: :desc)`. Also the opposite of incoming is outgoing not `outcomnig`.

Comment: @max nope, thats not correct. If user will have dialog only with one outcome message @user.incoming_messages.order(created_at: :desc) will not return this message. Also - this will return only list of messages, i need it to be grouped in dialogs. I have solution for MySQL, but mongo is more complicated in this question